# setter is not receiving value when variable is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider, setter

i arranged to call a setter function when a variable is changed. it's getting the value from a UISlider object and sending it to the setter of an NSInteger variable. By the time it reaches the setter code, the variable that was passed equals 0. i tried to typecast the float value (since it's UISlider.value) to NSInteger, but it still didn't work. it just keeps showing up as 0. i was hoping for a little help. here's some code:

```
@synthesize sleepTimeValue = _sleepTimeValue;
```

the function:

```
- (void)setSleepTimeValue:(NSInteger)aSleepTimeValue {
    NSLog(@"\n\
          Sleep Time Value - SETTER CALLED.\n\
          aSleepTimeValue: %ld\n\
          _sleepTimeValue: %ld\n", (long)aSleepTimeValue, (long)_sleepTimeValue);
    if (_sleepTimeValue != aSleepTimeValue) {
        _sleepTimeValue = aSleepTimeValue;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kPASetSleepTimeValue object:self];
    }
}
```

and when i change the variable:

```
NSLog(@"sleepTimeValue from qualityButtonPressed: %ld\nsliderValueLabel: %ld\nhoursSlider: %ld\n", (long)self.sleepTimeValue, (long)[self.sliderValueLabel.text integerValue], (long)self.hoursSlider.value);
self.sleepQualityValue = selectedIndex+1;
self.sleepTimeValue = (long)self.hoursSlider.value;
```

result right before the setter is called:

```
hoursSlider: 10
```

result from within the setter:

```
Sleep Time Value - SETTER CALLED.
aSleepTimeValue: 0
_sleepTimeValue: 0
```

Comment: Have you tried just creating a NSNumber from the slider value with [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.hoursSlider.value]?

Comment: What is the value of `self.hoursSlider.value` that is causing the error?

Comment: What does your code that actually handles the slider look like? I assume you have an IBAction that calls setSleepTimeValue on the valueChanged event?

Comment: no, there isnt any code that handles the slider event. the user moves the slider to reflect the time they slept, and then below the slider they pick the quality of sleep. when the quality of sleep is chosen, it is supposed to set the duration and quality together from that IBAction. which should call the setter

Comment: the value of self.hoursSlider.value is 10. it was a float but i typecast it to an int before attempting to save it to sleepTimeValue.

Comment: i did try creating an NSNumber. it didnt work. same results